# Sumar valores de una lista enlazada

Tags: javascript, lista

me toma los primeros dos valores ,pero no logro llegar al ultimo en el ej el 7 y en el caso que sean 4 tampoco puedo sumarlos todos. Queria aplicarle la recursion partiendo de current.next pero no funciona tampoco.
Implementar el método count dentro del prototype de LinkedList que deberá retornar la suma de todos los

```
  valores dentro de la lista.
  En caso de que la lista esté vacía, retornar 0
  Ejemplo:
  Dada esta lista: [4] --> [2] --> [7] -- > null
  //                                c           
  LinkedList.count() --> 13



LinkedList.prototype.count = function() {



mi codigo es el siguiente:



let current = this.head;
 let sum = 0;

  while(current.next != null){ 
    sum += current.value + current.next.value
    current = current.next
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: no se que lenguaje es... pero si miras siempre el siguiente, no vas a sumar nunca el ultimo....

Comment: javaScript es el leguaje

Comment: y porque no lo pusiste como etiqueta??? asi todos sabemos el lenguaje...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arreglo el ejmplo, con una lista simple (tecnicamente tampoco se deberia llamar count el metedo, si no mas bien "sum"):

```
function LinkedList() {

    let Node = function (value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }

    let length = 0;
    let head = null;

    this.append = function (element) {
        let node = new Node(element), current;
        if (head === null) {
            head = node;
        } else {
            current = head;
            while (current.next) {
                current = current.next;
            }
            current.next = node;
        }
        length++;
    }

    this.count = function () {
        let current = head;
        let sum = 0;

        while (current.value) {
            sum += current.value;
            current = current.next;
        }

        return sum;
    }
}

let mi_lista = new LinkedList();

mi_lista.append(4);
mi_lista.append(2);
mi_lista.append(7);
mi_lista.append(null);

console.log(mi_lista.count())
```

Comment: Me podrias explicar la linea de abajo del while

Comment: Si, (aclaro que edite un detalle):  sum += current.value + (existe el siguiente ? entonces retorno current.next.value: de lo contrario 0)

Comment: No estas sumando dos veces cada cosa?

Comment: Si, ahi lo arreglo.